# nvd3 as service in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am trying to create a SPA in which each page had different sets of line charts.
I have created a graph service.

```
dashboard.factory('graphService', function() {

function drawGraph(chart, element, data) {
    nv.addGraph(function() {
        chart = nv.models.lineChart()
            .x(function(d) { return d.x })
            .y(function(d) { return d.display ? d.display.y : d.y });

        chart.lines.scatter.useVoronoi(false);

        var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[0]; })]);

        chart.xAxis
            .axisLabel('Time')
            .tickFormat(function(d) {
                return d3.time.format("%m-%d %H:%M:%S")(new Date(d))
            })
            .scale(xScale)
            .orient("bottom");

        chart.yAxis
            .axisLabel('Rate')
            .domain([0, 20])
            .tickFormat(d3.format(',r'));

        d3.select(element)
            .datum(data)
            .transition().duration(500)
            .call(chart);

        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

        return chart;
    });
}

 return 
 {
    drawGraph: drawGraph
 };
});
```

However on the second page, I see the graph on the first page or sometimes I don't see

```
function refreshAcs() {

    graphService.drawGraph(that.acsChart, '#chartAcs svg', dataService.getAcsData());
}
```

how can I accomplish that? do I need to add callback to get the chart back and pass it every time? as the function is generator

Answer (score 3):

There is an angular directive for nvd3

http://cmaurer.github.io/angularjs-nvd3-directives

You can take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue in the past rendering multiple nvd3 charts on the same page (with rails not with Angular) the issue is that you can't have multiple graphs on the same page unless you store them all in an array. See [This Stackoverflow question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222968/dynamic-creation-of-multiple-nvd3-charts-with-rails-partial) for which you could extend the logic.

I came to this solution by viewing the examples page on [nvd3.org](http://nvd3.org) where I saw that they had their multiple graphs in an array. In their case however they are able to reference the graphs by name. you will simply have to do it dynamically. With angular's two way binding it might be a bit easier.

You will need to do something similar in Angular where you maintain an array of chart objects in your service. This shouldn't be a problem as angular services are singleton.

P.S. have you looked at using something like the angularjs-nvd3-directives project on github? might already do what you need with isolate scopes etc. #justathought

Good luck.